# How to use createFriendShip(..) in Twitter4J?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

```
builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(pref.getString("CONSUMER_KEY", ""));
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(pref.getString("CONSUMER_SECRET", ""));

    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(pref.getString("ACCESS_TOKEN", ""), pref.getString("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET", ""));
    twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);
    try {
        twitter.createFriendship("barackobama",true);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
       Log.e("Hata : ",e.getMessage());
    }
```

I get This Error 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
                                                                          message - You are unable to follow more people at this time. Learn more http://support.twitter.com/articles/66885-i-can-t-follow-people-follow-limits'>here.
                                                                          code - 161

When I use it in console twitter i can follow people but . when i try it in Twitter4j i cant follow people Why ? can anyone help me My Last Lib Version is 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You will experience different (more lenient) behaviour from official Twitter clients like web, Android and iPhone than from 3rd party clients.

https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364

> These limits include actions from all devices, including web, mobile, phone, API, etc. API requests from all third-party applications are tracked against the hourly API limit. People who use multiple third-party applications with their account will therefore reach the API limit more quickly. For more information on this topic, please see our API Rate Limiting page.

Comment: i am using the Android API KEYs